# add class of radio button label

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="form-radios" id="edit-attributes-1">
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-1">
 <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="1" name="attributes[1]" id="edit-attributes-1-1">  <label for="edit-attributes-1-1" class="option">0 </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-1">
 <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="2" name="attributes[1]" id="edit-attributes-1-2">  <label for="edit-attributes-1-2" class="option">2 </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-1">
 <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="3" name="attributes[1]" id="edit-attributes-1-3">  <label for="edit-attributes-1-3" class="option">4 </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-1">
 <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="4" name="attributes[1]" id="edit-attributes-1-4">  <label for="edit-attributes-1-4" class="option">6 </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-1">
 <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="5" name="attributes[1]" id="edit-attributes-1-5">  <label for="edit-attributes-1-5" class="option">8 </label>

</div>
</div>
```

I have this type structure of radio button in drupal add to cart form.  I have to add "active" class on **clicked radio button's label (not on radio button)** and remove "active" class from other from other **clicked radio button's label (not on radio button)**. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Pure CSS solution (that should work in all modern browsers, if it’s just for styling purposes): http://jsfiddle.net/2FHKS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('label').addClass('active');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2FHKS/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('.form-radio').on('click', function() {
        $('.form-radio').each(function() { 
             $(this).next().removeClass('active');
        });
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
            $(this).next().addClass('active');
    });
});
```